# angularjs xdomain socket timeout

Tags: angularjs, iframe, cors, postmessage

I am running an Angular app on my local machine which connects to a local API via CORS. The app runs on localhost:8000, and the API runs on localhost:7999.

In the past I have counted on [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) to handle my IE9 compatibility, but this time I'm not having any luck with it. Here's the console log from IE9...

```
LOG: xdomain (localhost:8000): adding slave: 'localhost:7999'

LOG: xdomain (localhost:8000): proxying request to slave: 'localhost:7999'

LOG: xdomain (localhost:8000): creating iframe xdomain-8f12dd3f

LOG: xdomain (localhost:8000): new socket: xdomain-20f6dbf3

xdomain (localhost:8000): Timeout waiting on iframe socket
```

Has any one else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.

It turned out my proxy.html (needed for xdomain) was being sent with a 'X-Frame-Options' header, which was preventing the page working in an iFrame which is what xdomain uses.

Removing the 'X-Frame-Options' header from proxy.html on your server or web framework should be able to solve your problem. Make sure you're only removing it for proxy.html though.